# sed replace with hex

Tags: linux, sed, grep

UTF-8 file test.txt:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

hex is

```
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
```

`sed s/A/B/g test.txt` works

`sed s/\x41/B/g test.txt` does not work

Some characters are unprintable so I must use their hex, `A` is just an example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the shell preprocesses it, use single quotes.

```
sed 's/\x41/B/g' test.txt

echo -e \x41   # x41
echo -e '\x41' # A
```

Comment: thanks!  echo -e '\x41' # A is all right, but sed 's/\x41/B/g' test.txt  is not.

Comment: $ `echo A | sed 's/\x41/B/g'` => B. GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: seems to be system-specific on mac os x

Comment: BSD sed does not seem to support hexadecimal escape codes, but should support octal escape codes. Perhaps \101 instead of \x41 will work (can't test myself; macbook is elsewhere).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Could you please extend your solution for unicode characters? I've tried `sed 's/\x20\x13/B/g' test.txt` but it did not work (I refer [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) character).

Comment: @dma_k: what's your encoding? the byte sequence must be something elsse. check the page you referred to... eg the UTF-8 seq is: 0xE2 0x80 0x93

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to replace individual characters, you should be able to use tr with octal escapes like this:

```
tr '\101' B
```